# Is it possible to use CPU graphic card while I connect to DisplayPort on a nvidia card?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, intel-core-i5, 4k-resolution

I bought intel i5 6600k which has a graphic card supports 4k @ 60HZ. But my motherboard don't have DisplayPort (only has a HDMI 1.4 whichi supports 4k @ 24HZ), so I'm thinking buy a [nvs 310](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nvs-310-graphics-card.html) which has two DisplayPort 1.2. Then connect the monitor through the DisplayPort on it and use the intel graphic card with 4k @ 60HZ? Is that possible?

Note: the spec of nvs 310 says it supports max resolution at 2560 * 1600. It connects to the motherboard with PCIE 2.

Comment: Are you talking about on-board graphics? If so I would not expect to see it running comfortably at 4k.

Comment: @Tealkine Yes, the graphics integrated with CPU. Why is that?